# Getting element from html to js

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to import the id's element instead of hard coding the whole banner in the js. The issue that I'm facing is I can't import the element and manupulate it as I like. for Gg getting length of it. JS done in diffrent script.

```
const typingText = document.getElementById("typingText");
const words = ["Welcome!"];
let wordIndex = 0;
let letterIndex = 0;

function typeWords() {
  if (letterIndex < words[wordIndex].length) {
    typingText.innerText += words[wordIndex].charAt(letterIndex);
    letterIndex++;
    setTimeout(typeWords, 200);
  }
}
typeWords();
```

This the the code that works instead of

```
const words = ["Welcome!"];
```

I want it to take the element from the HTML id `typingText`.

This is what I tried

```
const typingText = document.getElementById("typingText");
const words = myElement.innerHTML;
let wordIndex = 0;
let letterIndex = 0;

function typeWords() {
  if (letterIndex < words[wordIndex].length) {
    typingText.innerText += words[wordIndex].charAt(letterIndex);
    letterIndex++;
    setTimeout(typeWords, 200);
  }
}
typeWords();
```

Comment: i tried using both string and array it didnt work. thank you for your help David.

Answer (score 1):

In the working code you define an array:

```
const words = ["Welcome!"];
```

In the non-working code, you define a string:

```
const words = myElement.innerHTML;
```

As nothing else has changed, you probably wanted that to be an array:

```
const words = [myElement.innerHTML];
```

Comment: Clearly that's what they want, since the function uses `words[wordIndex].length`, which expects `words` to be an array.